# Error while compiling c++ code with clang Xcode 5.0.2 in OS X Mavericks 10.9.3

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile, clang

I'd like to know the reason of getting the `error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'` and some solution to overtake this error. This problem appears when I try to compilate a c++ bitcoin's blockchain parser project. Actually it seems the author of this project just has compilated it in Ubuntu OS, although I'm trying to get this code compilated in my OS X.

Below is the output of the `make` command:

```
c++ -- cb/allBalances.cpp
c++ -- cb/allAddresses.cpp
c++ -- callback.cpp
c++ -- cb/dumpTX.cpp
c++ -- cb/closure.cpp
c++ -- cb/help.cpp
c++ -- option.cpp
c++ -- opcodes.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
make: *** [.objs/allAddresses.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
make: *** [.objs/allBalances.o] Error 1
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
make: *** [.objs/help.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/closure.o] Error 1
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
make: *** [.objs/dumpTX.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/callback.o] Error 1
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
make: *** [.objs/opcodes.o] Error 1
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
make: *** [.objs/option.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Check `man clang` for valid options.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, they are so optimisation levels.